# C# Using struct in XmlSerializer without creating a separate xml node

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I have a class I want to serialize to an Xml:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "readCase", Namespace = "XXX")]
public class ReadCase
{       
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "versionAsOf", Namespace = "XXX")]
    public BaseUtcTimeStamp VersionAsOf { get; set; }
}
```

I created a struct BaseUtcTimeStamp:

```
[Serializable]
public struct BaseUtcTimeStamp
{
    private string _utcTimestamp;

    public string UtcTimestamp { get => _utcTimestamp; set { } } // set is needed for XmlSerializer

    public BaseUtcTimeStamp(DateTime utcDateTime)
    {
        if (utcDateTime.Kind != DateTimeKind.Utc)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Given dateTime must be Utc.");
        }

        _utcTimestamp = utcDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");
    }
 }
```

The serialized XML looks like below:

```
<case:readCase>
   <case:versionAsOf>
     <case:UtcTimestamp>2021-07-01T07:38:14Z</case:UtcTimestamp>
   </case:versionAsOf>
 </case:readCase>
```

I want the BaseUtcTimeStamp type value to be directly within VersionAsOf (like a GUID). Example:

```
<case:readCase>
   <case:versionAsOf>2021-07-01T07:38:14Z</case:versionAsOf>
 </case:readCase>
```

Comment: Note: you don't need `[Serializable]` here - it has nothing to do with xml serialization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[XmlText]
public string UtcTimestamp { get => _utcTimestamp; set { } }
```